# Convert string encoded as byte array into character array without using java.lang.String

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-encoding

I have a byte array which contains a string encoded with some character set, which is some sensitive data (like password). I would like to convert it into character array, but without using `String` (i.e. NOT something like `(new String(bytes, charset)).toCharArray()`), because this is sensitive data. Is it possible? i.e. I would like to have something like:

```java
public static char[] convertByteArrayToCharArray(byte[] data, Charset charset) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a way:

```java
public static char[] convertByteArrayToCharArray(byte[] data, Charset charset) {
    return charset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
}
```

More strict version:

```
public static char[] convertByteArrayToCharArray(byte[] data, Charset charset) {
    charset.newDecoder()
       .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
       .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
       .decode(data); 
}
```